# Where should I search to see if a proof/identity has already been discovered? If it has, is it still "mine"?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question

I've independently discovered a few identities related to the golden ratio and the generalized Fibonacci sequences. I've looked through the obvious sites (Wikipedia, the OEIS) to see if they've been posted there, and they haven't. However, though the identities are certainly not trivial, their proofs are surprisingly simple, and it seems very likely that someone has already published them in some obscure article or another. Are there comprehensive "proof repositories" I can go through? And if they have been discovered before, I feel like I should say so in any papers I write that include the identities, but since I didn't actually utilize their work in any way, the citation should be different than if I had. Is there an accepted way to give whoever discovered them first their due (though I couldn't possibly know for sure if they were the first) without ceding all credit to them?

I'm not simply looking to see if these specific identities have been discovered; I want to know this for the sake of all work I do in the future. However, just in case some of you happen to know something I don't, I'll provide a link to one of them. I posted it to the OEIS (http://oeis.org/A001622, under Formulas, by Isaac Saffold on February 28, 2018).

EDIT: I realize that the example I gave may be a bit too trivial to be a good one. Like I said, this question isn't about a specific discovery I've made, but about good practice in general.

Comment: Proof repositories are known as "journals".

Comment: Well, $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}/ \phi^{n+k}=\phi^{-n}\cdot (1+\phi^{-1})^n=1^n=1$

Comment: Shark, I know I can look through journals, and I've looked through some articles already. I'm looking for an even more comprehensive resource, perhaps a database that includes articles from multiple journals.

Comment: A comment about something being "yours": many mathematicians could have said that about something, and were anyway "victims" of [Stigler's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy). Only History will tell.

Comment: I highly doubt there's anything like what I'm asking about, but there's no harm in checking anyway.

Comment: And Hagen, $(1 + \phi^-1) = \phi)$. Take the case for $n=0$. It's simply $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{0 \choose k}}{\phi^k} = 1$. For $n=1$, it's $phi^-1 + phi^-2$. Both equal 1. You can continue on in that manner and see for yourself.

Comment: There are four possible reasons for not finding something in journals: 1/ it's wrong 2/ it's here and you didn't find 3/ it's not here and you have found something nontrivial 4/ It's not here, it's true, but it's trivial and nobody would seriously bother to publish that. Hagen has given an hint for answer 4/ to your first equation. The others are direct applications of the series $\sum_{n\ge0} x^n=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: That being said, the first is interesting. In the form $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\phi^{-k}=\phi^n$, it can be related to the [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform). (but honeslty even this form is easily proved with the binomial transform of $a^n$, which is also trivial)

Comment: Trust me, I know they're not significant enough to be the topic of a publication. But I may certainly use them for more significant proofs, or just mention them for their own sake in an article about the golden ratio in general. The fact that the golden ratio is the sum of the powers of its reciprocal is just beautiful to me. My question still applies, I think.

Comment: If you are interested in literature about the golden ratio and Fibonacci sequences my advice is that you can see what kind of articles and advanced problems are being published in   [$\mathcal{The Fibonacci  Quarterly}.$](https://www.fq.math.ca/) Good luck.